# how to do autocomplete in angularjs using JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am a beginner of Angular js, I have tried autocomplete using jqueryUI,

my json format like below:

```
{'476':'A.S.Peta','1051':'Aachara','91402':'Aadesar(Gujrat)'}
```

I have struck for how to do,

please help,thanks advance

Comment: you could go for angular-ui typeahead http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: @PankajParkar: i am able to do if have list in array but I want to do using JSON like this format {'476':'A.S.Peta','1051':'Aachara','91402':'Aadesar(Gujrat)'}